# Funding for Belgian student to do a PhD in UK?

Tags: phd, funding, united-kingdom

I am currently applying for PhD fundings in UK, but as the competition is rude, I am not sure to be accepted, even if I have very good grades and qualifications.

So, I want to look at other PhD fundings opportunities, that may be less obvious. For instance, I know that the European Commission proposed some PhD fundings (Marie Curie scheme or something like that), but I think it is no longer active.

If you could give me some advice, I would greatly appreciate.

Field of study : Theoretical Physics
Country of origin : Belgium, EU.

I'm not wealthy enough to fund myself for my PhD, even for one year.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're looking at the UK, and not other countries? In my opinion, conditions for PhD students are better in other countries (NL, BE, DE, Nordic countries...), as they are employed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top universities often have a lot of reasonably obscure funding options.

For example with the University of Cambridge - if you go through the steps at [this website](http://webservices.admin.cam.ac.uk/camfunds/gfinder.jsp?status=new&reset=reset) they list *all* their funding options, you'll see for Physics there are fully-funded scholarships such as these that *might* be of interest to you:

- Leslie Wilson Research Scholarship (£17,427 per year)
- Winton Scholarship(s) in the Physics of Sustainability
- Thalmann Bequest (covers EU fees only)
- Schiff Fund (upto £20,000 per year)
- Gulbenkian Studentship (specifically for non-UK nationals)
- [Gates Cambridge Scholarships](http://www.gatescambridge.org/)

The equivalent website for the University of Oxford is [here](http://www.ox.ac.uk/feesandfunding/search/)

and it reckons

> 35 Scholarships were found for a new student from Belgium studying
>   Theoretical Physics (DPhil)

so I'm not going to list them all here!!!

Best of luck!